# Auto reply to emails that have specific word in the subject or body

Tags: gmail

I am not sure where else to ask this so apologies in advance.

It looks like some idiot with the same first initial as me has used my email address to sign up to a bunch of car and house sale mailing lists in Milwaukee (I'm not even in the USA)

I want to be able to reply to any email that contains this person's name with a message along the lines of

> "This is an automated response.  I am not [idiot with same initial as
>   me].  That person has given you my address by mistake.  Please remove
>   me from your mailing list"

I have tried doing this using gmail templates,  but in the gmail filters the option 'send template' doesn't offer an option to choose who to send it to.  There is no option to 'reply with template'.

I know I can just include a delete filter (and have done), or click 'unsubscribe,  but in my years of experience with spam it is virtually pointless to click the 'unsubscribe' link in the emails,  and I would like to inform the people who were given my email address that they were given it by mistake so that they stop wasting their time.

I tested the rule by sending myself emails containing the name,   the delete rule appears to work but I don't get auto replies.

So is there an alternative way to auto reply to emails that contain a specific word, in gmail?

Answer (score 0):

The **Send Template** option in the Gmail Filter settings do exactly what you want. It replies to any email matching the filter with the selected template email message.

[image]

It "*doesn't offer an option to choose who to send it to*" because being an action of a filter it will always mean that it replay to any email matching this filter.

Comment: But it is not doing that.   My tests confirm.  The emails are getting deleted so the filter itself is apparently working,  just not the send template part.

Comment: @MrVimes, in my test it did work without issue

Comment: I will try again.  I wonder if it is something to do with my template (My template has the to field left blank for obvious reasons,  does it need something in there?)

Comment: No certainly not. Templates cannot have a To address saved, even if you have a To address when you save the template it will not save along with the template.